# javascript functions and properties

Tags: javascript, function

I add properties to this function in this way and then I log the function to the console.

```
function x(){

}

    x.y = 5
    x.z = 10
    x.propertyTest = () => {
        return "this is the result"
}

console.log(x) returns { [Function: x] y: 5, z: 10, propertyTest: [Function] }
```

It seems that it is not putting these properties into the x function but instead is putting the x function and all the properties we added into an object and then automatically declaring this new object as the x function.

Is this what is happening?

Comment: Functions **are** objects.

Comment: Everything in JavaScript is objects, and you can add properties to them.

Comment: well by the looks of it the function and the properties are getting put into a new object. So how do you explain that?